# Javascript/JQuery Regex remove spaces, parenthesis, periods, minus in link only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have gotten this far thanks to a lot of searching, but I am stuck on a way to format the link only and not the text.  I would like the link to have the numbers in the text, but without spaces, parenthesis, periods or the minus symbol and leave the text as is.  The link should have as an example `<a href="tel:+15551231234">555 123-1234</a>`

```
<div id="phonedirectory">
    <ul>
        <li>Phone 1 - 555 123-1234</li>
        <li>Phone 2 - 555.123.4321</li>
        <li>Phone 3 - (555) 123-6789</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    var regex = /\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4}/g;
    var text = $("body:first").html();
    text = text.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:+1$&\">$&</a>");
    $("body:first").html(text);
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Wherever you were searching, it was in the wrong place if that's the solution you found.

Comment: @wared thank you for the welcome....this is my first time here on StackOverflow....lots of knowledgeable folks on here to help...this is awesome

Comment: I agree, a great place to learn and share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't (!) regex-replace the entire HTML of your page. Ever. This is asking for trouble.

The correct approach is more complicated. But in return it's... well... correct.

```
var phonePattern = /\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4}/g,
    phoneReplacement = '<a href="tel:+1$&">$&</a>';

function replacePhoneNumbers(container) {
    $(container).contents(":not(a)").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (this.nodeType === 3) {
            $(this).replaceWith( $this.text().replace(phonePattern, phoneReplacement) );
        } else {
            return replacePhoneNumbers(this);
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    replacePhoneNumbers(document.body);
});
```

The function is recursive. It inspects the entire container you give it (`document.body` in this case) and replaces text nodes specifically (`nodeType === 3`) *but only if* they are not already part of a link.

This way only those parts of the document are treated that acutally need treatment. The rest of the document is kept unchanged. No re-renders occur, no layout changes and no risk of breaking the document tree if you mess up the regular expression.

---

You can even roll that into a jQuery plugin if you want.

```
$.fn.extend({
    phonelinkify: function (pattern, replacement) {
        return this.contents().each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (this.nodeType === 3 && $this.parents("a").length === 0) {
                $(this).replaceWith( $this.text().replace(pattern, replacement) );
            } else {
                return $(this).phonelinkify(pattern, replacement);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and

```
$(function () {
    $("#phonedirectory").phonelinkify(/\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4}/g, '<a href="tel:+1$&">$&</a>');
});
```

---

To make a more custom replacement, change the `phoneReplacement` variable to a function.

```
phoneReplacement = function (num) {
    return '<a href="tel:' + num.replace(/\D/g, "") + '">' + num + '</a>';
};
```

This will turn `Phone 3 - (555) 123-6789` into

```
Phone 3 - <a href="tel:5551236789">(555) 123-6789</a>
```

This works with both the original and the plugin version of this answer. [Read up on `.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to understand how passing functions as a replacement works.

---

Disclaimer: Whether the regular expressions in use here are completely appropriate for phone number matching or not (I very much doubt they are) is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: thank you for the code above, but how do you get the link only to be without spaces, periods, parenthesis, minus symbol and leave the text of the number as is?

Comment: Thank you again....I am going to use the second option... jQuery plugin, with the custom replacement.  I put it together and tested it out and it works great with my test page.  I am really interested in the way to use RegEx with jQuery....both of those combined could be a powerful tool, however used sparingly.

Comment: @Steve Make sure you take your time to understand the solution. Copy-pasting code off the Internet that you do not really understand is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
$('li').html(function (i, html) {
    var text = html.split(' - ').slice(1).join(' - '),
        num = text.match(/\d+/g).join('');
    return '<a href="tel:+1' + num + '">' + text + '</a>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would do this without using a regex.

```
var numOnly = function (inputString) {
    var validChars = "0123456789";
    var outputString = '';

    var len = inputString.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (validChars.indexOf(inputString[i]) > -1) {
            outputString += inputString[i];
        }
    }

    return outputString;
}

var phoneNumber = numOnly(phoneNumberString);
```